# Read Information from garmin

Tags: dictionary, geospatial, garmin

I want to extract information such (longitude,latitude,location name) from garmin maps
and use the database  of this info in my java web application.
but i dont know how to extract a region information such as a city from a garmin map as text or binary.
If anyone know about it help me please.

Answer (score 5):

Garmin maps are copyrighted binary files. Extracting this data without a license to do so is illegal. Don't do it.

The information you seek may be available from the USGS site for free in an easy-to-use text format:
http://geonames.usgs.gov/domestic/

Alternatively, consider using one of google or yahoo's excellent geolocation APIs.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/index.html

http://developer.yahoo.com/maps/